# No overload matches this call. Error in a NodeJS application written in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, serialization, passport-local-mongoose

This is my `models/user.ts` file:

```
import mongoose , {Schema , Document , Model} from 'mongoose';
import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';

export interface digitalWalletDocument extends Document{
    currencyName: string;
    value: number;

}

const digitalWalletSchema = new Schema<digitalWalletDocument>({
    currencyName : {
        type : String
    },
    value : {
        type : Number
    }
});


export interface UserDocument extends Document{
    username :  string;
    firstName : string;
    lastName : string;
    email : string;
    telNumber : number;
    nationalCode : number;
    admin : boolean;
    image :  string;
    wallet : number;
    rate : number;
    shabaCode :number;
    cardNumber : number;
    birthDay : string;
    status : string;
    address : string;
    documnetPath : string;
    description : string;
    purchased : string;
    digitalWallet : digitalWalletDocument;
}

export const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>({
    username : {
        type : String,
        sparse : true ,
        unique : true
    },
    firstName : {
        type: String
    },
    lastName : {
        type : String
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        unique : true
    },
    telNumber : {
        type : Number
    },
    nationalCode : {
        type : Number,
        sparse : true,
        unique : true
    },
    admin : {
        type:Boolean,
        default : false
    },
    image : {
        type : String
    },
    wallet: {
        type : Number,
        default : 0
    },
    rate : {
        type : Number,
        default : 0
    },
    shabaCode : {
        type : Number
    },
    cardNumber : {
        type : Number
    },
    birthDay : {
        type : String
    },
    status : {
        type : String
    },
    address : {
        type : String
    },
    documnetPath : {
        type : String
    },
    description : {
        type: String
    },
    purchased : [String],
    digitalWallet : [digitalWalletSchema]
}, {timestamps : true});

export interface UserModel extends mongoose.PassportLocalModel<UserDocument>{};

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose,{usernameField : 'email'});

export default mongoose.model<UserDocument,UserModel>('User' , userSchema);
```

And the following is my `authentication.ts` file:

```
import express, {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import passport, { authenticate } from 'passport';
import passportLocal from 'passport-local';
const LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
import passportJWT from 'passport-jwt';
const passportJWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
import JWT from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from './models/users';
import config from './config';

export const local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
    
export function getToken(user: any) {
    return JWT.sign(user, config.secretKey,{ expiresIn : "2d"});
};

const opt = {
    secretOrKey : config.secretKey,
    jwtFromRequest : ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
};


export const jwtAuth = passport.use(new passportJWTStrategy(opt , (payload ,done) => {

    User.findOne({_id : payload._id},(err: any , user: typeof User ) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err,false);
        }
        else if(user){
            return done(null , user);
        }
        else{
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));

export const verifyUser = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session : false});

export function verifyAdmin(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    if(req.user.admin){
        return next();
    }
    else{
        let err = new Error('Only Admin can access to this web page or resources!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
}
```

I get the following error message in `passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());`  line of the code:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(fn: (user: User,
> done: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void): void', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(user: UserDocument, cb: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(user: User,
> done: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'user' and 'user' are incompatible.
> Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'UserDocument': username, firstName, lastName, email, and 66 more.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(fn: (req: IncomingMessage, user: User, done: (err:
> any, id?: unknown) => void) => void): void', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(user: UserDocument, cb: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req:
> IncomingMessage, user: User, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void)
> => void'.
> Types of parameters 'user' and 'req' are incompatible.
> Type 'IncomingMessage' is missing the following properties from type 'UserDocument': username, firstName, lastName, email, and 66
> more.ts(2769)

Also another errors occurs at these lines of the code:

```
if(req.user.admin)
```

and

```
err.status = 403;
```

And the error messages are:

> Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)
>
> Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'.ts(2339)

I don't know what is the problem and how can I fix it? This code works in `JS` version of the application but I don't know why gives me this error in `TS` version?

Comment: It shouldn't be `typeof User`. Only `User`. `typeof User` is the class constructor, while `User` is an instance type.

Comment: When I change it to `User` it gives me: `'User' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof User'?ts(2749)` error.